# How to change theme for AlertDialog in ListPreference?

Tags: android

I know that HoloEverywhere is not suppoted ListPreference, but supports AlertDialog. Can I override AlertDialog in ListPreference to HoloEverywhere.AlertDialog ?

Comment: Have you looked into Android themeing? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html